Did Protagoras really think that holding the javelin responsible was a viable resolution to the Lancer's Trilemma?
From Wikipedia:

Plutarch wrote that Pericles and Protagoras spent a whole day discussing an interesting point of legal responsibility, that probably involved a more philosophical question of causation: "In an athletic contest, a man had been accidentally hit and killed with a javelin. Was his death to be attributed to the javelin, to the man who threw it, or to the authorities responsible for the conduct of the games?"

...something does not seem sane about this. No matter how ignorant the Ancient Greeks were, it is 100% certain that Protagoras did not think that the javelin itself--an inanimate object--could be held morally responsible. Because such a thing would have been unheard of (that is, new) to these men.
Therefore I request an expert in Ancient Greek philosophy to clarify matters. What did Protagoras actually think about his trilemma please? And if he truly did think this, where is the corroborate evidence?

According to Plutarch who is the source for this incident, the idea that Pericles spent a whole day discussing this may have been a lie made up by Pericles' son Xanthippus to discredit him.
https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Plutarch/Lives/Pericles*.html

So much, then, for his public troubles; they were likely soon to cease, now that the multitude had stung him, as it were, and left their passion with their sting; but his domestic affairs were in a  p105 sorry plight, since he had lost not a few of his intimate friends during the pestilence, and had for some time been rent and torn by a family feud. The eldest of his legitimate sons, Xanthippus, who was naturally prodigal, and had married a young and extravagant wife, the daughter of Tisander, the son of Epilycus, was much displeased at his father's exactitude in making him but a meagre allowance, and that a little at a time.
172
2 Accordingly, he sent to one of his father's friends and got money, pretending that Pericles bade him do it. When the friend afterwards demanded repayment of the loan, Pericles not only refused it, but brought suit against him to boot. So the young fellow, Xanthippus, incensed at this, fell to abusing his father, publishing abroad, to make men laugh, his conduct of affairs at home, and the discourses which he held with the sophists. 3 For instance, a certain athlete had hit Epitimus the Pharsalian with a javelin, accidentally, and killed him, and Pericles, Xanthippus said, squandered an entire day discussing with Protagoras whether it was the javelin, or rather the one who hurled it, or the judges of the contests, that "in the strictest sense" ought to be held responsible for the disaster. Besides all this, the slanderous charge concerning his own wife Stesimbrotus says was sown abroad in public by Xanthippus himself, and also that the quarrel which the young man had with his father remained utterly incurable up to the time of his death, — for Xanthippus fell sick and died during the plague.


Aha! That would suffice to explain why Xanthippus included such a blatant non-sequitur. Thank you.

@Fomalhaut Of course, Plutarch didn't exactly know Xanthippus was making it up - he just suspected based on Xanthippus' conflict with his father. Perhaps Xanthippus was reporting something that actually happened. Maybe pinning the blame on the javelin would be like the custom of ritualistically placing sins on a "scapegoat." Alternatively, maybe Pericles was arguing about causation rather than legal responsibility. Or maybe the distinction between the two was blurred at the time. We just don't know; from Pericles to Xanthippus to Plutarch, it's a game of telephone.

What is a very refractory problem then?
